# Name list of data frames from data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, names

I usually read a bunch of .csv files into a list of data frames and name it manually doing.

```
#...code for creating the list named "datos" with files from library 
# Naming the columns of the data frames
names(datos$v1r1)<-c("estado","tiempo","x1","x2","y1","y2")
names(datos$v1r2)<-c(...)
names(datos$v1r3)<-c(...)
```

I want to do this renaming operation automatically. To do so, I created a data frame with the names I want for each of the data frames in my `datos` list.

Here is how I generate this data frame:

```
pru<-rbind(c("UT","TR","UT+","TR+"),
            c("UT","TR","UT+","TR+"),
            c("TR","UT","TR+","UT+"),
            c("TR","UT","TR+","UT+"))

vec<-paste("v1r",seq(1,20,1),sep="")
tor<-paste("v1s",seq(1,20,1),sep="")


nombres<-do.call("rbind", replicate(10, pru, simplify = FALSE))

nombres_df<-data.frame(corrida=c(vec,tor),nombres)
```

Because `nombres_df$corrida[1]` is `v1r1`, I have to name the `datos$v1r1` columns `("estado","tiempo", nombres_df[1,2:5])`, and so on for the other 40 elements.
I want to do this renaming automatically. I was thinking I could use something that uses regular expressions.

Just for the record, I don't know why but the order of the list of data frames is not the same as the 1:20 sequence (by this I mean 10 comes before 2,3,4...)

Here's a toy example of a list with a similar structure but fewer and shorter data frames.

```
toy<-list(a=replicate(6,1:5),b=replicate(6,10:14))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data frame where variable `corridas` is the name of the data frame to be renamed and the remaining columns are the desired variable names for that data frame. You could use a loop to do all the renaming operations:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(nombres_df))) {
  names(datos[[nombres_df$corridas[i]]]) <- c("estado","tiempo",nombres_df[i,2:length(nombres_df)])
}
```